# Yii2 download image without extension from URL at backend

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a admin account at backend in my system and I need to download from URL without extension.

I created a `actionDownload` in my controller and inside it I have this line of code:

```
$myUrl = "https://via.placeholder.com/150";
Yii::$app->response->sendFile($myUrl, 'test.png');
```

How can I download the image without extension from URL?

Comment: Is it for third party url or your application url?

Comment: @InsaneSkull it is for third party url